# Perl: Simple INI file info retrieval

Tags: perl, file, config, ini

I have a perl script that's reading an INI file like this:

```
[placeholder_title]
Hostname = 127.0.0.1
Port = 161
```

The library that I'm using for this is Config::Tiny.

Normally when reading the ini file, I would have something like this:

```
$Config = Config::Tiny->read( 'configfile.ini' );

my $Hostname_property = $Config->{placeholder_title}->{Hostname};
```

Now I have a case where the section title in the config file is decided by the user, so I don't exactly know what it is.

Before I actually had multiple sections in the config file, so I would iterate through them like this:

```
 foreach my $Section (keys %{$Config}) {

            my $Hostname_property = $Config->{$Section}->{Hostname};
            my $Port_property = $Config->{$Section}->{Port};
```

But what if I were to have only 1 section in total?

Is there a particular keyword I can use to substitute for the section name?

I've tried the similar looping logic from the prior example something like this:

```
$Config = Config::Tiny->read( 'configfile.ini' );

my $Section = keys %{$Config};

my $Hostname_property = $Config->{$Section}->{Hostname};

print $Hostname_property, "\n";
```

But then I get an error that $Hostname_property is not initialized, so my $Section variable clearly isn't doing what I hoped it to do.

If anybody can help me out or at least point me in the right direction, it would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason `my $Section = keys %{$Config};` doesn't work is that you're calling `keys` in scalar context, so it's returning the number of keys.  Try calling it in list context instead:

```
my ($Section) = keys %{$Config};
```

This will set `$Section` to the first key. ("first" in whatever order `keys` is returning the keys in.  If there's only one key, that doesn't matter.)

Answer (score 2):

It's okay for a hash to have only one key.  Consequently, it's okay if there's only one section in your ini file.

For example, if we have a file called `blah.ini` with contents of

```
[title]
foo=bar
blah=baz
```

and if we run the following code:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Config::Tiny;
my $cfg=Config::Tiny->read("blah.ini");
use Data::Dumper;
print Dumper($cfg) . "\n";
```

Then we get the output

```
$VAR1 = bless( {
                 'title' => {
                              'blah' => 'baz',
                              'foo' => 'bar'
                            }
               }, 'Config::Tiny' );
```

Consequently, we can do something like the following:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Config::Tiny;

my $cfg=Config::Tiny->read("blah.ini");
foreach my $title(sort keys %$cfg)
{
  foreach my $setting (sort keys %{$cfg->{$title}})
  {
    print "title: $title,setting $setting, value $cfg->{$title}->{$setting}\n";
  }
}
```

And the output is

```
title: title,setting blah, value baz
title: title,setting foo, value bar
```